Differential in Minkowski/Non Euclidean space
Generally I know that a 1-form can be written as a contraction $\omega_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$, but to me it is not clear what to do when I am in a Minkwoski space, should I take into consideration the signature (-,+,+,+) (this is just my book convention ),
when I expand a 1-form so I would get $ \omega= -\omega_{0}dx^{0} + \omega_{i}dx^{i}$ or just   $ \omega= \omega_{0} dx^{0} + \omega_{i}dx^{i}$
For example suppose I have some time dependent change of coordinates
$
\begin{cases}
t=t \\ x= \rho\cos(\alpha-\omega t) \\
y= \rho\cos(\alpha-\omega t) \\
z= z
\end{cases}
$
and say I would like to write $dx$.
Should I have to write:
$$dx={-}\omega\rho\sin(\alpha-\omega t)dt+\cos(\alpha-\omega t)d\rho-\sin(\alpha-\omega t)d\alpha$$
or
$$dx=\omega\rho\sin(\alpha-\omega t)dt+\cos(\alpha-\omega t)d\rho-\sin(\alpha-\omega t)d\alpha$$

The underlying metric has nothing to do with the expansion of a differential form in local coordinates. We can in fact work with covariant and contravariant tensors on a manifold with no metric whatsoever. The metric only comes into play when we want to raise or lower indices.

Thank you, very much!
